# how do i get a new time out of datetime

Tags: python

I am writing a alarm clock program and running into a issue where the time in date time isn't updating.
here is my code:

````
from datetime import datetime
from pygame import mixer

DT = str(datetime.now().hour) + ":" + str(datetime.now().minute)

AT = str(input("What Time Would You Like To Wake Up [hour:minute]: "))

while 1 == 1:
    if DT == AT:
        mixer.init()
        mixer.music.load('alarmClock.mp3')
        input("Are You Awake [PRESS ENTER TO STOP]")
        break
    else:
        DT = str(datetime.now().hour) + ":" + str(datetime.now().minute)```
````

Comment: Why do you think the datetime isn't updating?

Comment: May I see the output of: `print(AT)`

Comment: bro this code is working fine  for me ,,either you trace each line  by line with use of print statement and check format of AT and DT

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
AT = str(raw_input("What Time Would You Like To Wake Up [hour:minute]: "))
```

instead of:

```
AT = str(input("What Time Would You Like To Wake Up [hour:minute]: "))
```

Comment: @ila is better use while True instead of while 1 == 1